# Fire event on expanderView item selection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I have a expanderview in my application and I'm trying to fire an event when the user selects an item from the expanderview but I can't for the life of me get this to work.

my xaml looks like this:

```
<!--Custom header template-->
<DataTemplate x:Key="CustomHeaderTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="" FontSize="28" />            
</DataTemplate>

<!--Custom expander template-->
<DataTemplate x:Key="CustomExpanderTemplate">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Width="400" Height="60" Fill="#FFF1F1F1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" StrokeThickness="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding procedureName}" FontSize="30" Foreground="#FF00457C" FontWeight="Normal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" />

    </Grid>

</DataTemplate>

<!--Custom expander items template-->
<DataTemplate x:Key="ExpanderViewItems" >

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="15" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Source="{Binding flagIcon}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBlock FontSize="26" Text="{Binding N}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding RNG}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>                
        <TextBlock FontSize="26" Text="{Binding ValueAndUnit}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Medium" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding COM}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <Line StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#C4C6CC" Stretch="Fill" X1="0" X2="1" Y1="0" Y2="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<!--Listbox Containing ExpanderViews-->
        <ListBox Name="testsList" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <!--ExpanderView-->
                    <toolkit:ExpanderView Header="{Binding}"                                                   
                                          HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource CustomHeaderTemplate}"
                                          Expander="{Binding}"
                                          ExpanderTemplate="{StaticResource CustomExpanderTemplate}"
                                          x:Name="expander" 
                                          FontSize="36" 
                                          Foreground="#FF00457C" 
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding testItems}"
                                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ExpanderViewItems}" >                          
                    </toolkit:ExpanderView>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

So there you have it, just need to simply fire an event when a user selects an expander item, finding it extremely tedious.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `MouseLeftButtonUp` event handler on the Item Container of your ItemTemplate which is a Grid control:

```
<!--Custom expander items template-->
<DataTemplate x:Key="ExpanderViewItems" >

    <Grid MouseLeftButtonUp="ItemSelected">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="15" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Source="{Binding flagIcon}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBlock FontSize="26" Text="{Binding N}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding RNG}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>                
        <TextBlock FontSize="26" Text="{Binding ValueAndUnit}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Medium" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding COM}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <Line StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#C4C6CC" Stretch="Fill" X1="0" X2="1" Y1="0" Y2="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried that but then instead of firing the event when an expanderViewItem is selected it fires after clicking on the expanderViewExpander to view all it's items...

Comment: So in affect it's fired when a dropdownbox is clicked, not when an item in a dropdownbox is clicked.